# Is deviance a relevant metric for non-linear (neural) model?

Tags: neural-networks, generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression, deviance

Is [**deviance**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deviance_(statistics)) a relevant metric for non-linear (e.g. neural network) models?

$$
D(y,\hat\mu)=2\left ( log((p(y|\hat\theta_{s})) - log(p(y|\hat\theta_{0})))) \right )
$$

For example, when we model Poisson regression and the neural model estimates $\lambda$ as non-linear dependent variable of $\boldsymbol{X}$.

If so, can you use such deviance to compare results with neural networks to GLM models?

They are not necessary nested. Yet according to the *deviance* definition we compare residual log-likelihood to the saturated model, which shall looks the same in both cases.

E.g for the Poisson regression:

$$
d(y,\hat\mu)=2\left( y \space log(\frac{y}{\hat\mu}) - y + \hat\mu \right )
$$

where $y$ is datapoint from the dataset and $\hat\mu$ is estimated mean for given $\boldsymbol{X}$.